# Issue with Cloud sql connection on App Engine for django project

Tags: mysql, django, google-app-engine, web-deployment, google-app-engine-python

I am trying to deploy my django project on Google App Engine following the documentation https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine. But I cannot establish proxy connection with sql server. 
Here is my database credentials from settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST': '/cloudsql/x-reviews:us-central1:x-reviews-stage',
        'NAME': 'x_reviews_stage',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'my-password',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

I use following query to connect to proxy server

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances="x-reviews:us-central1:x-reviews-stage"=tcp:3306
```

To start mysql instance, there are 2 ways- TCP based connection and UNIX based connection as mentioned in the link
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy
When I try TCP based connection using below query, connection is established

```
mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --user root --password
```

When I try UNIX based connection using below query, I receive the error

```
mysql -u root -p -S /cloudsql/x-reviews:us-central1:x-reviews-stage
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/cloudsql/x-reviews:us-central1:x-reviews-stage' (2)
```

Similarly, I receive the error when I try to run django project

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/cloudsql/x-reviews:us-central1:x-reviews-stage' (2)")
```

Searched the Internet, Read the Google documentation multiple times but I am stuck here for 2 days. How do I establish connection with SQL server? My goal is to deploy the project. As per the documentation, I need to create database by running the app locally with remote connection to cloudsql proxy server. How do I solve the issue?

Comment: Are you trying to use the Unix socket based connection locally? It will only work when the app is being run on App Engine, not on your local machine.

Comment: I was using Unix based connection as per the documentation. So, how do I use TCP based connection to   establish remote connection with my django project (still on local machine) in order to migrate database? OR is there any other way so that I can deploy the project first and then connect with the database?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to establish TCP based connection with the server.